# Pass variable from one function of JS to another function of JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am calling Showmenu() JavaScript function from C# and passing one variable to this function. Now I want to use this variable in another function of JavaScript.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
 var strmenu;
 function ShowMenu(strmenu) {
 alert(strmenu); 
 }
 alert(strmenu);   
 ddsmoothmenu.init({
 mainmenuid: strmenu,  
 orientation: 'h',  
 classname: 'ddsmoothmenu',               
 contentsource: "markup")}
 </script>
```

I am calling `ShowMenu(strmenu)` function in c sharp.....like

```
menu_Sysadmin.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:return ShowMenu('sysadmin')");
```

I want to use `strmenu` from `showmenu()` in  `ddsmoothmenu.init()` as a parameter. alert shows value but when I am trying to use `strmenu` as globally, it is not working.

Comment: The code in the script block shown isn't even complete (you've opened a call to `init` without closing it, and opened an object initializer to pass into it without using it). Separately, **how** are you calling JavaScript from C#?

Comment: yeah right but this was not solve my problem. & i can call a javascript function in c sharp.     menu13_Sysadmin.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:return ShowMenu('sysadmin')");

Answer (score 4):

Your `strmenu` parameter hides the global variable. You have to rename either the global variable or the parameter of your function and perform an assignment in your function.

```
var menu;
function ShowMenu(strmenu) {
    menu = strmenu;
}
```

Comment: i was tring this also but not working thats why m using same name of variable.

Comment: I'm guessing ddsmoothmenu.init is being called before ShowMenu() which is why this will not work. How is ShowMenu() being called?

Comment: Using the same name **can't** work, because you can't access your global variable in a scope where a variable or parameter with the same name is defined. Your problem might be that your `init` function is called _before_ the `ShowMenu` function. The `init` function is called immediately after loading the `script` tag. Due to the lack of code, I can only guess - but I think `ShowMenu` is called later, so the variable assignment happens after `init`.

Comment: ShowMenu() calling from csharp like    menu13_Sysadmin.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:return ShowMenu('sysadmin')");

Comment: ddsmoothmenu.init is being called on Page Load but you are only calling ShowMenu() onclick - so when ddsmoothmenu.init runs the strmenu value has not yet been set so this will never work.

Comment: i want 'sysadmin' as a parameter of init function.

Comment: Then you have to call `ddsmoothmenu.init()` from within your `ShowMenu()` function.

Comment: Now alert in showmenu() shows value of menu  but outsite alert function not show value.

Comment: Yes, because the outside code is executed **before** `ShowMenu()`. `ShowMenu()` is called when you click. `init()` is called when the page is loaded because it is not inside any function. Just try putting the `init` code block inside your `ShowMenu()` function.

Comment: @fero  `<script type="text/javascript" > 
    var menu;
       function ShowMenu(strmenu) {
           alert(strmenu);
           menu = strmenu;
           ddsmoothmenu.init({
               mainmenuid: menu, 
               orientation: 'h', 
               classname: 'ddsmoothmenu', 
               contentsource: "markup" 
           })
       }   
    </script>`

Comment: I found some [docs for your smooth menu](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm). Unfortunately you can't initialize the menu after page load because the `init` function creates a `ready` handler for the document. It appears to me that you have to initialize _all_ your menus on page load and then show a particular menu on click. But I'm not going to read the full documentation for you... ;-)